# Expected identifier, string or number with *[Symbol.iterator]

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, iterator

Here is my demo which is working on `jsfiddle`:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(...names) {
        this.animals = names
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let animal of this.animals) {
            yield animal
        }
    }
}
var animals = new Animal('cat', 'dog', 'tiger');
for (let animal of animals) {
    console.log(animal)
}
```

But when I rewrite it in Visual Studio:

```
class Animal {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {

    }
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Expected identifier, string or number

[image: 1]

So, my question: how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a generator using the `class` syntax. This is a direct translation of your code into ES6 that actually functions.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(...names) {
    this.animals = names
  }
}

// you could define the generator on the prototype here ...
// but make sure you read the second half of this answer
Animal.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  for (let animal of this.animals) {
    yield animal
  }
}

var animals = new Animal('cat', 'dog', 'tiger');
for (let animal of animals) {
  console.log(animal)
}

// cat
// dog
// tiger
```

But that's not really how you're supposed to do things. The `Symbol.iterator` only needs resolve an *iterable value* — [Array.prototype.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) will provide just the thing you need

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(...names) {
    this.animals = names
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.animals.values()
  }
}

var animals = new Animal('cat', 'dog', 'tiger');
for (let animal of animals) {
  console.log(animal)
}

// cat
// dog
// tiger
```

You *can* define the iterator as a generator like you did in your OP, but you will have to use *delegation* (`yield*`) to get the behavior you desire -

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(...names) {
    this.animals = names
  }
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield* this.animals
  }
}

var animals = new Animal('cat', 'dog', 'tiger');
for (let animal of animals) {
  console.log(animal)
}

// cat
// dog
// tiger
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: this.animals.values is not a function`